# Unable to infer type of a closure parameter in the current context RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have this function

```
    func authorizeUser(user: User) -> Completable {
    let client = Client(name: user.username!, allowedGrantTypes: ["password", "refresh_token"])
    return self.userGateway.postClient(client: client)
        .flatMap { [weak self] authorizedClient in
             (self?.userGateway.getToken(authModel: AuthModel(
                                            clientId: "\(authorizedClient.id!)_\(authorizedClient.randomId!)",
                                            grantType: "password",
                                            username: user.username!,
                                            password: user.password!,
                                            clientSecret: authorizedClient.secret!)))!
        }.flatMap { token in
            self.settings.token = token
            return self.userGateway.getCurrentUser(token: token)
        }.map { user in
            self.settings.account = user
        }.asCompletable()
}
```

And it works fine. But when I'm trying to make AuthModel as variable and put it as function parameter I'm getting error "Unable to infer type of a closure parameter 'token' in the current context".What am I doing wrong? My function with error looks like below

```
    func authroizeUser(user: User) -> Completable {
    let client = Client(name: user.username!, allowedGrantTypes: ["password", "refresh_token"])
    return self.userGateway.postClient(client: client)
        .flatMap { [weak self] authorizedClient in
            let authModel = AuthModel(
                clientId: "\(authorizedClient.id!)_\(authorizedClient.randomId!)",
                grantType: "password",
                username: user.username!,
                password: user.password!,
                clientSecret: authorizedClient.secret!)
            return (self.userGateway.getToken(authModel: authModel))!
        }.flatMap { token in
            self.settings.token = token
            return self.userGateway.getCurrentUser(token: token)
        }.map { user in
            self.settings.account = user
        }.asCompletable()
}
```

Comment: You already have the correct answer. A nice solution IMO, is to move that `let authModel = ...` into a `map` just before your flatMap. Then you can avoid declaring the return type of the `flatMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. That's just how Swift works. As soon as a closure of unknown return type is more than one line in length, you have to tell the Swift compiler its return type, explicitly; the compiler can no longer infer it by looking at the closure contents.  So simply do that.